# Validation to refuse empty or minimal entries

Tags: php

When I enter only one input and submit it enters the database. When I submit empty forms it creates space inside the database.

I want 1) When the user leaves the form empty and submits, refuse to be inserted 2) When the user inputs 1 or 2 inputs and submits, refuse to submit.

```
include 'database/dbconfig.php';
$insert =new connection($DB_con);
$full_name = "";
$email = "";
$mobile= "";
$noc ="";
$message = "";
$full_nameerror = "";
$email_error = "";
$mobile_error ="";
$noc_error ="";
$message_error="";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  // checking null values in message
    if (empty($_POST["full_name"])){
        $full_nameerror = "Please enter your name";
      } 
   else {
       $full_name = test_input($_POST["full_name"]);
       // check name only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$full_name)){
            $full_nameerror = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
         }
     }
 // checking null values in message  
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
       $email_error = "Please enter your email";
      } 
   else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      }
 // checking null values in message    
   if (empty($_POST["mobile"])) {
      $mobile_error = "Please enter your mobile number";
     }
   else { 
      $mobile = test_input($_POST["mobile"]);  
     } 
      if (empty($_POST["noc"])) {
      $noc_error = "Nature of contact is required";
     } 
   else { 
      $noc_error = test_input($_POST["noc"]);  
     } 
// checking null values in message
   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
      $message_error = "Please enter your message";
     } 
   else { 
      $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);  
     } 
    if ($full_name|| $email || $mobile || $email || $noc || $message != "")
if ($insert->create($full_name,$email,$mobile,$noc,$message)) 
{
        echo "Record inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "error in executing query";
}




}
  else
 {
     echo "Empty input submit2"; // empty $_POST["submit2"]
 }


function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="contact-form">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Form Name -->
            <legend class="text-center" ><h2>Contact form</h2></legend>

             <div id="error">
                <!-- error will be shown here ! -->
                </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="full_name">Full Name</label>  
              <div class="col-md-5">
              <input id="full_name" name="full_name" placeholder="Enter your full name" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
              <span class="help-block" style="color:red;"><?php echo $full_nameerror;?></span>  
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
              <div class="col-md-5">
              <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control input-md"  type="text">
              <span class="help-block" style="color:red;"><?php echo $email_error;?></span>  
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="mobile">Mobile(Optional)</label>  
              <div class="col-md-5">
              <input id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" class="form-control input-md"  type="text">
              <span class="help-block" style="color:red;"><?php echo $mobile_error;?></span>  
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Select Basic -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="noc">Nature of Contact:</label>
              <div class="col-md-5">
                <select id="noc" name="noc" class="form-control">
                  <option value="">Select a Nature of Contact</option>
                  <option value="Request_for_a_service">Request for a service</option>
                  <option value="Report_an_issue">Report an issue</option>
                  <option value="Enquire_about_us">Enquire about us</option>
                  <option value="Work_with_us">Work with us</option>
                  <option value="Commend_us">Commend us</option>
                  <option value="Other_issue">Other issue</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Textarea -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="message">Message</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">                     
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>  <span class="help-block" style="color:red;"><?php echo $message_error;?></span>  
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Contact us</button>
```

This is my class

```
<?php
class connection
{
 private $db;
 public $DB_con;

 function __construct($DB_con)
 {
  $this->db = $DB_con;
 }

 public function create($full_name,$email,$mobile,$noc,$message)
 {

  try
  {
   $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO form(full_name,email,mobile,noc,message) VALUES(:fname, :email,:mobile,:noc,:message)");
   $stmt->bindparam(":fname",$full_name);
   $stmt->bindparam(":email",$email);
   $stmt->bindparam(":mobile",$mobile);
   $stmt->bindparam(":noc",$noc);
    $stmt->bindparam(":message",$message);
   $stmt->execute();
   return $stmt;
  }

  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage(); 
   return false;
  }
  }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm assuming all fields are required, so `if ($full_name|| $email || $mobile || $email || $noc || $message != "")` makes no sense as you are saying if one of these fields are present, then add it into the table.
2. Except for trimming, keep the data in its original raw form when you submit it to the database. Unless you have [magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on (which you shouldn't have), you should not be stripping any slashes. As you are correctly using prepared statements, there is no need to do that. As well, you should not be escaping any HTML prior to inserting into the database; you do that only when you are outputting it.
3. You should trim before using `empty()` because `empty('') === true` whereas `empty(' ') === false`.
4. You use too many variables.

Here's a revision:

```
include 'database/dbconfig.php';

$conn = new connection($DB_con);

$full_name = "";
$email = "";
$mobile= "";
$noc ="";
$message = "";

// associative array to hold all your error messages; 
// the keys are the names of the inputs and the values are the associated messages
$errors = array();

// trim POSTed values
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);

// check if form was submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // validate fields
    if (empty($_POST["full_name"])) {
        $errors['full_name'] = "Please enter your name";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $_POST["full_name"])) {
        $errors['full_name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    } else {
        $full_name = $_POST["full_name"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $errors['email'] = "Please enter your email";
    }  else {
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    }  
    if (empty($_POST["mobile"])) {
        $errors['mobile'] = "Please enter your mobile number";
    } else {
        $mobile = $_POST["mobile"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["noc"])) {
        $errors['noc'] = "Nature of contact is required";
    } else {
        $noc = $_POST["noc"];
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $errors['message'] = "Please enter your message";
    } else {
        $message = $_POST["message"];
    }
    // check if there are any errors
    if ($errors) {
        echo "error in form";
    // otherwise try adding a record
    } elseif ($conn->create($full_name, $email, $mobile, $noc, $message)) {
        echo "record inserted";
    } else {
        echo "error in inserting data";
    }
}
```

For showing any errors, you would do something like

```
<?php if (isset($errors['full_name'])) : ?>
    <span class="help-block" style="color:red;"><?= $errors['full_name'] ?></span>
<?php endif ?>
```